# How to tell if someone is cheating and report them in pokémon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

The game was recently launched in my country and all gyms close by are occupied by level 20+ trainers with cp 2000+ rare pokémons.

A quick search revealed other players in my country complaining about the same thing and a link to report players (https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319948).

How do I know if the player is indeed cheating or just played the game too much? Is 2000+ CP possible to achieve without cheating? And what information I should include in my report to Niantic?

Comment: The game was available in all countries through certain means before it was officially launched in your country. These people have been playing since the game was launched outside of your country and, while they have advantage over people starting only now, it's not really cheating.

Comment: Also, could they have come from a nearby country where they were already playing too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are suspicious, report them. It's not your job to be 100% certain.

Niantic have access to far more resources than you do for verifying if they are playing legitimately. Bring any evidence you have to their attention and let them handle it.

Comment: Official Niantic report form: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319948

Comment: I agree with the point that you not need to be 100% certain. However, it seems from Niantic's report system is automated. I have heard a lot of reports that 3 reports on a specific player will get them banned automatically. But it makes sense considering there are millions of players and so they probably won't look at each report individually

Comment: Just as @CreativiTimothy said, the way niantic handles reports indicates that you don't need to be cheating to get banned. If you suspect a player of cheating don't assume the worst at first. For example when capturing a gym without actually being there he could be hiding very well, in a car, or just living in a nearby house and his location is determined a little inaccurately.

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way to find out if a player is cheating, is by first identifying the player in the wild. Next, follow them everywhere. Make careful notes where they go, what they eat, when they use their phone. Install some camera's in their bedroom and the bathroom, in case they play Pokemon GO when they go to the toilet. Peak through their windows at night.

In the end you should have enough information to know how much time they spend playing Pokemon GO, as well as a restraining order, criminal record and the distrust of everyone around you.

---

No seriously: **If they are cheating, Niantic will automatically identify them as such, and ban them.** They have much more data that can be used to find inconsistenties. "They are high level and thus they must be cheating" is a bad reason to suspect someone. Enjoy the game yourself, or with your friends, and just assume that if someone is a higher level, they earned it in a honest way.

Comment: Jokes aren't allowed on Arqade :/

Comment: The first part of the answer is to show OP that their line of thinking is wrong. If it reads as a joke, it is because it is absurd. It is also the only way a regular user can know if someone else they don't know is cheating. The second part is completely serious: Niantic will identify them as such. They don't need you to act as a police officer, and especially not as a crazy town mob, carrying torches and pitch forks, screaming "witch" at everything they don't like.

Comment: I agree with you entirely, however, it seems that the sense of humor on here is limited.

Most people, unfortunately, will only read the first half of the first paragraph before deciding "Nope", and downvoting.

Comment: I reported the guy in the morning, and he was gone in the afternoon. After he was gone, there were a bunch of people with normal levels fighting for the gym. In some games it is possible to tell if someone is cheating. If a guy shows up with level 9999.... and it would take a year playing 24/7, then that guy is cheating. I don't know if this game you can make that type of calculation, so that is why I asked. Is 2000+ CP so high to be impossible to achieve without cheating? I don't know, and I would like to know.

Comment: _Is 2000+ CP so high to be impossible without cheating?_ No, it isn't - it takes time, but it's entirely possible. I almost have my Arcanine there, I'm on level 24 and haven't been cheating. There's plenty around here on level 30+ and I've seen a Dragonite in a gym over 3000+ CP.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it tries to bagatelize a completely valid question as niantic seems to ban after 3 reports, even when the player is not cheating. Now the question is protected so while I actually have useful suggestions on determining if an other player is cheating from ingame behavior I cannot post it as an answer.

Comment: 10 reputation is not that much to earn. Simply answer one other question and gather 1 upvote. Or post a good question and gather two. Or get at least 200 reputation on any stackexchange site and get 100 for free on every SE site.